# links per page and page size limits

Tags: google, links, bing, page, page-size

This is a setup I have on my site photo directory pages:

[image: links]

On the desktop site, Users can choose to select one from a maximum of 100, 200 or 500 photo thumbnails per page.

I feel now at the rate technology is moving and because the pages load very fast, I'm tempted to eliminate the choices and allow users to select one from up to 500 photo thumbnails per page.

While this pleases a large number of guests on the site, I'm not sure how much it pleases Google because as of the first decade of the year 2000, they indicated that websites should have no more than 100 links per page and the 500 thumbnails means 500 links. I think they also indicated back then that a page that exceeded 100kb won't get processed.

How do all the major search engines respond to 500 links per page today? would they still happily accept it or would that exceed their internal link or page size limits?

Comment: Great minds think alike... of course so do warped ones!